# How does the shutdown work in executors?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, executorservice

I have a `ScheduledExecutorService` and I do a task every 15 mins (in a web application in Tomcat).
In a `ServletContextListener` in `contextDestroyed` I have done:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){  
            @Override  
            public void run(){  
                scheduler.shutdown();   
            }   
        });
```

The scheduler is started like:

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("My task");
                //Do some task
            }

        };
updater.scheduleWithFixedDelay(r, 30, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Question:On `shutdown` any remaining task isn't executed.
There is a task running but I don't see any logs so it seems it is not executed. Why?

**UPDATE:**
If I start tomcat and then after 2 mins I shutdown then isn't the task considered as scheduled and must run?  I mean if a task is submitted isn't it considered as pending? Or it must be actually running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite parse your question but maybe your application is not exiting like you'd expect?

Shutting down an `Executor` will stop any tasks for being submitted but any running tasks will continue to run until they exit.  From the `shutdown()` javadocs:

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted
>   tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.
>   Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.

If you edit your question to be more clear we can answer more appropriately.

Comment: I run in Tomcat.The shutdown is inside the ServletContextListener. I stop using `shutdown`

Comment: Usually, you need to implement your own logic to either 1) process all (or some with a timeout) outstanding messages in the queue or 2) save the messages and process them when the application is restarted (usually done via JMQ with persistent queues)

Comment: I still don't quite understand your question @Jim.  Can you edit the question and be more precise?  You provide shutdown code but maybe your issues is that your background task isn't running at all?

Comment: @AngerClown:JMO?How is this related to my question?

Comment: I meant JMQ, as a way to store outstanding messages at shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly wait until all running tasks are finished, do something like this:

```
try {
  // Wait for one second indefinitively
  while (!scheduler.awaitTermination (1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    // wait until completion
  }
} catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
  // interrupted... you may log something
}
```